# CAMetalLayer nextDrawable memory leak?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

I am currently investigating a memory leak in iOS.

We have a ViewController and a view for that Controller.
The ViewController is currently pushed and popped repeatedly (for debugging purposes).
The view contains a `CAMetalLayer` (the class method `layerClass` returns `CAMetalLayer`) and a `CADisplayLink` which calls my render method.
When I call `[metalLayer nextDrawable]` for the first time, the app allocates approximately 20MB.
however, only a fraction of it is released when the ViewController is popped!
i am 100% certain that I dont have retain cycles or anything.

Here is my initialization code for the rendering:

```
-(void)initializeRendering {
@autoreleasepool {
    id<MTLDevice> device = [[MetalRenderingSession sharedInstance] renderDevice];
    [self setCommandQueue:[device newCommandQueue]];
    CAMetalLayer* layer = static_cast<CAMetalLayer*>([self layer]);
    layer.device = device;
    layer.pixelFormat = MTLPixelFormatRGBA16Float;
    layer.framebufferOnly = true;
    layer.maximumDrawableCount = 2;
    layer.contentsScale = [self contentScaleFactor];
    [self setMetalLayer:layer];
    CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    MTLTextureDescriptor* depthTextureDescriptor = [MTLTextureDescriptor texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat:MTLPixelFormatDepth32Float
        width:static_cast<NSUInteger>(screenSize.width) height:static_cast<NSUInteger>(screenSize.height) mipmapped:NO];
    [depthTextureDescriptor setUsage:MTLTextureUsageRenderTarget];
    id<MTLTexture> depthTexture = [device newTextureWithDescriptor:depthTextureDescriptor];
    [self setTextureDepth:depthTexture];
    [self updateOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] size:[self frame].size];
    CADisplayLink* renderLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(render)];
    [renderLink setPreferredFramesPerSecond:30];
    [self setDisplayLink:renderLink];
    [renderLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}
}
```

here is my actual render code:

```
-(void)render {
@autoreleasepool {
    dispatch_semaphore_wait([self renderCommandExecuting], DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [[self commandQueue] commandBuffer];
    [[self commandQueue] insertDebugCaptureBoundary];

    //commenting next line and lines that use drawable makes memory leak disappear?
    id<CAMetalDrawable> drawable = [[self metalLayer] nextDrawable];
    id<MTLRenderCommandEncoder> encoder = [self createCommandEncoderfromCommandBuffer:commandBuffer andDrawable:drawable];
    //creating ViewPort here
    [encoder setViewport:viewport];

    //doing rendering here, but for debugging purpoeses i disabled rendering 
    [encoder endEncoding];
    [commandBuffer presentDrawable:drawable];

    [commandBuffer addCompletedHandler:^(id<MTLCommandBuffer> o) {
        dispatch_semaphore_signal([self renderCommandExecuting]);
    }];
    [commandBuffer commit];
    [commandBuffer waitUntilCompleted];
}
}
```

[image]

to me, it looks like for every `CAMetalLayer`, the app creates a `IOSurface`
, but how can I release these?

the diagram is stepped, because i wait 2 seconds before popping the view controller.
The "steps" appear when I push the view controller.
I noticed that only "VM:IOSurface" climbs up, the rest stays the same.

here is my cleanup code (within view, called from `viewWillDisappear`):

```
-(void)stop {
[[self displayLink] setPaused:YES];
[[self displayLink] removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
//those are 4*4 float arrays, they are allocated in the view's init
free([self projectionMatrix]);
free([self viewMatrix]);
free([self modelMatrix]);
[self setCommandQueue:nil];
[self setMetalLayer:nil];
[self setTextureDepth:nil];
[self setRenderCommandExecuting:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was `CADisplayLink`.
You need to use `-[[CADisplayLink]invalidate]` to properly release it.
Removing it from the RunLoop manually is not enough.